# Which names are given at burial?

Tags: minhag, names, funeral-burial-levaya

The custom is for the Chevra Kadisha to name a baby who dies before being named.

What names are customarily used in this sad scenario?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there are different names that are used in general that you think to ask what they are?

Answer (score 7):

R Jason Weiner (senior rabbi at Cedars-Sinai hospital in Los Angeles), in his article [Jewish Guidance on the Loss of a Baby or Fetus](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol23Weiner.pdf) (Hakirah vol. 23) writes

> - **It is customary to give the baby or fetus a name that is somewhat uncommon** (Minchat Shlomo 2:96(2); Nishmat Avraham, YD 263:5(14) (365
>     in 3rd ed.). R. Auerbach gives the examples of **Metushelach** and
>     **Rachamim** (in those communities in which this would not be a common
>     name). See Ke-Chalom Ya’uf, 102 for other examples of commonly used
>     names in these circumstances. R. Elchonon Zohn told this author that
>     another commonly used name is **Yonah**, particularly if the gender is
>     indistinguishable, because of a midrash stating that the prophet Yonah
>     ben Amitai had been a child who died and was resurrected.)
> - **but some advise choosing a more usual name** (Ke-Chalom Ya’uf, 44)
> - **parents should therefore seek Rabbinic guidance and choose a name that they prefer** (ibid., 43–4. If the parents do not choose a name,
>     the mortuary (Chevrah Kadisha) will often choose one)

May God comfort all families suffering such a terrible experience. And as with all personal issues, please [ask your rav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) for any personal ruling.